# Galois Theory References

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, symmetric-polynomials

This may not initially be a well posed question, but I'm looking for a good reference on Galois theory that covers it from the viewpoint of the symmetry in roots of an irreducible polynomial and not a field extension.  It's well known that a generic polynomial has Galois group $S_n$, and this can be interpreted as saying the only relations satisfied by  the roots are expressed by symmetric polynomials and the coefficients of the original polynomial (eg, the constant term is the product of all roots).  Then to get a smaller group, one has extra implicit relations among the roots.  (I'm having trouble finding an example to even look at right now, but in the case of deg 3, you would have a polynomial whose Galois group is cyclic so you get three relations as above, but there must be one other relation which is not symmetric under an element of order two in $S_3$.)  Can we give some criteria to determine when you have extra relations, or, if you know the group is not all of $S_n$, can we say what these relations are?  (I like to think of this as cutting down the size of the Galois group by adding equations - similar to intersecting hypersurfaces, say.)

Another way to think of this is that, for fixed degree $n$, we get a stratification of $\mathbb{Q}^{n-1}$, (or your favorite field) by associating to $(a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1})$ the Galois group of $x^n + a_1 x^{n-2} + \ldots + a_{n-2} x + a_{n-1}$.  Would this stratification be 'nice'?

Comment: You had used a ) instead of a }. We all know that pain.

Comment: Thanks!  I graduated in '08 and haven't thought much about mathematics since then...I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: If I understand correctly pretty much every Galois theory reference is fine.  Studying the symmetry of roots of an irreducible polynomial is the same thing as studying the Galois group of its splitting field.  The second part of your question seems to be asking about the Galois correspondence (between subfields of the splitting field and subgroups of the Galois group).

Comment: You're right in that the relations are determined by the group itself so to know one is to know the other.  I don't think there's much hope for the second part, either as looking at the polynomial isn't the most natural way to do this - many polynomials produce isomorphic field extensions.  You'd be better off looking at something like a moduli space of field extensions and stratifying that by the associated Galois group.  I'm curious if you can construct this as a geometric object, perhaps a quotient of affine space?